# How to tell setuptools to install requirements quietly?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-pbr

Is there a way to tell setuptools with [PBR](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/) to install packages from `requirements.txt` and `test-requirements.txt` quietly?

With this command:

```
python setup.py --quiet test
```

I am getting all messages from `pip`, which I would like to avoid.

My `setup.py` is:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(setup_requires=["pbr", "setuptools", "pytest-runner"], pbr=True)
```

And `setup.cfg` contains (except for `metadata`):

```
[aliases]
test=pytest
```

---

What I want to achieve is configure setuptools/PBR, so that the effect is the same as with running:

```
pip install --quiet --requirement requirements.txt
pip install --quiet --requirement test-requirements.txt
python setup.py --quiet test
```

but without calling `pip install --quiet`.